# GMail Calendar Invite Not Rendering When Sent via PHP Application

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, icalendar

I've found several other threads on similar topics, but my particular question might be more nuanced. I have an .ics iCalendar file which I'd like to use to send out event invitations from my Laravel (PHP) application.

The contents of this file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:www.example.org
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:53877c55800b2
DTSTAMP:20140529T182837Z
DTSTART:20140531T120000Z
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND:20140531T130000Z
SUMMARY:Intro to Web Design
ATTENDEE:example@gmail.com
METHOD:REQUEST
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When sent from my PHP application as an attachment, GMail recognizes the calendar invite (see the small calendar icon next to the date) but doesn't embed the actionable calendar widget like I'd expect.

However when I manually forward that thread to myself, sent from the GMail web UI, it does include the widget. (The 'View on Google Calendar' link is busted, going to http://www.google.com/calendar/undefined, but I'll work on that next)

See the contrast here: [image: blah]

Same exact .ics file. It gets 100 on http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/. As best I can tell this has maybe to do with GMail's spam protection filters. According to this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google for a related but different service, I need to authenticate with either SPF/DKIM which seems tough to swing from my local dev environment.

Any ideas? The documentation seems incredibly thin for how to make this GMail Invite widget appear. Thanks in advance!

Edit: adding raw source.

Sans-invite:

```
Return-Path: <jon.c.culver@gmail.com>
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (c-24-19-97-115.hsd1.wa.comcast.net. [24.19.97.115])
       by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id nh8sm30028762pbc.25.2014.05.28.14.58.35
       for <culvejc@gmail.com>
       (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
       Wed, 28 May 2014 14:58:35 -0700 (PDT)
Sender: Jon Culver <culvejc@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <d77e56242d5eb5b88c6a12c449a457d3@localhost>
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 21:58:34 +0000
From: Invite <jon.c.culver@gmail.com>
To: culvejc@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="_=_swift_v4_1401314314_7e69457c82922c70669b91e8f6f04aa0_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1401314314_7e69457c82922c70669b91e8f6f04aa0_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

You're invited!

Intro to Web Design

--_=_swift_v4_1401314314_7e69457c82922c70669b91e8f6f04aa0_=_
Content-Type: text/calendar; name=invite.ics
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics

QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KUFJPRElEOnd3dy5zZWF0dGxlZnJlZXNjaG9v
bC5vcmcNCkJFR0lOOlZFVkVOVA0KVUlEOjUzODY1YzBhNDIxZjMNCkRUU1RBTVA6MjAxNDA1MjhU
MjE1ODM0Wg0KRFRTVEFSVDoyMDE0MDUzMVQxMjAwMDBaDQpTRVFVRU5DRTowDQpUUkFOU1A6T1BB
UVVFDQpEVEVORDoyMDE0MDUzMVQxMzAwMDBaDQpTVU1NQVJZOkludHJvIHRvIFdlYiBEZXNpZ24N
CkFUVEVOREVFOmpvbi5jLmN1bHZlckBnbWFpbC5jb20NCk1FVEhPRDpSRVFVRVNUDQpFTkQ6VkVW
RU5UDQpFTkQ6VkNBTEVOREFS

--_=_swift_v4_1401314314_7e69457c82922c70669b91e8f6f04aa0_=_--
```

With invite added correctly:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Sender: culvejc@gmail.com
Received: by 10.170.223.212 with HTTP; Wed, 28 May 2014 14:58:54 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <d77e56242d5eb5b88c6a12c449a457d3@localhost>
References: <d77e56242d5eb5b88c6a12c449a457d3@localhost>
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 14:58:54 -0700
Delivered-To: culvejc@gmail.com
X-Google-Sender-Auth: 4NYaEgkYuT25UEyzdqbv3cPgdyY
Message-ID: <CABRfHznNc5fndT=L3X-BFDNseJ=gpX0Wwg4a9u96fzRzqRzPPQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Fwd:
From: Jon Culver <jon.c.culver@gmail.com>
To: Jon Culver <culvejc@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a1139d86a27ac0104fa7ceb83

--001a1139d86a27ac0104fa7ceb83
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1139d86a27abfe04fa7ceb81

--001a1139d86a27abfe04fa7ceb81
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Invite <jon.c.culver@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, May 28, 2014 at 2:58 PM
Subject:
To: culvejc@gmail.com


You're invited! Intro to Web Design

--001a1139d86a27abfe04fa7ceb81
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr"><br><br><div class="gmail_quote">---------- Forwarded message ----------<br>From: <b class="gmail_sendername">Invite</b> <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:jon.c.culver@gmail.com">jon.c.culver@gmail.com</a>&gt;</span><br>
Date: Wed, May 28, 2014 at 2:58 PM<br>Subject: <br>To: <a href="mailto:culvejc@gmail.com">culvejc@gmail.com</a><br><br><br>You&#39;re invited!

Intro to Web Design
</div><br></div>

--001a1139d86a27abfe04fa7ceb81--
--001a1139d86a27ac0104fa7ceb83
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=US-ASCII; name="invite.ics"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invite.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: a3995007e372820d_0.1

QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpWRVJTSU9OOjIuMA0KUFJPRElEOnd3dy5zZWF0dGxlZnJlZXNjaG9v
bC5vcmcNCkJFR0lOOlZFVkVOVA0KVUlEOjUzODY1YzBhNDIxZjMNCkRUU1RBTVA6MjAxNDA1MjhU
MjE1ODM0Wg0KRFRTVEFSVDoyMDE0MDUzMVQxMjAwMDBaDQpTRVFVRU5DRTowDQpUUkFOU1A6T1BB
UVVFDQpEVEVORDoyMDE0MDUzMVQxMzAwMDBaDQpTVU1NQVJZOkludHJvIHRvIFdlYiBEZXNpZ24N
CkFUVEVOREVFOmpvbi5jLmN1bHZlckBnbWFpbC5jb20NCk1FVEhPRDpSRVFVRVNUDQpFTkQ6VkVW
RU5UDQpFTkQ6VkNBTEVOREFS

--001a1139d86a27ac0104fa7ceb83--
```

Answer (score 1):

The `METHOD:REQUEST` property belongs in the outer VCALENDAR object and not to the VEVENT object, and as such should be put before the `BEGIN:VEVENT`.

You are also missing an ORGANIZER property.

Comment: Surely helped my VCALENDAR's correctness, but still no dice. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Well, then you probably need to go the multipart/alternative (MIME message with multipart/mixed (multipart/alternative (text/plain, text/calendar), text/calendar)

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel do it this way, bro:

```
    \Mail::send('yourMail/file', $data, function($message) use($data)
    {
        $filename = "invite.ics";
        $meeting_duration = (3600 * 2); // 2 hours
        $meetingstamp = strtotime( $data['start_date'] . " UTC");
        $dtstart = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $meetingstamp);
        $dtend =  gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $meetingstamp + $meeting_duration);
        $todaystamp = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
        $uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His').'-'.rand().'@yourdomain.com';
        $description = strip_tags($data['texto']);
        $location = "Telefone ou vídeo conferência";
        $titulo_invite = "Your meeting title";
        $organizer = "CN=Organizer name:email@YourOrganizer.com";

        // ICS
        $mail[0]  = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";
        $mail[1] = "PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN";
        $mail[2] = "VERSION:2.0";
        $mail[3] = "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN";
        $mail[4] = "METHOD:REQUEST";
        $mail[5] = "BEGIN:VEVENT";
        $mail[6] = "DTSTART;TZID=America/Sao_Paulo:" . $dtstart;
        $mail[7] = "DTEND;TZID=America/Sao_Paulo:" . $dtend;
        $mail[8] = "DTSTAMP;TZID=America/Sao_Paulo:" . $todaystamp;
        $mail[9] = "UID:" . $uid;
        $mail[10] = "ORGANIZER;" . $organizer;
        $mail[11] = "CREATED:" . $todaystamp;
        $mail[12] = "DESCRIPTION:" . $description;
        $mail[13] = "LAST-MODIFIED:" . $todaystamp;
        $mail[14] = "LOCATION:" . $location;
        $mail[15] = "SEQUENCE:0";
        $mail[16] = "STATUS:CONFIRMED";
        $mail[17] = "SUMMARY:" . $titulo_invite;
        $mail[18] = "TRANSP:OPAQUE";
        $mail[19] = "END:VEVENT";
        $mail[20] = "END:VCALENDAR";

        $mail = implode("\r\n", $mail);
        header("text/calendar");
        file_put_contents($filename, $mail);

        $message->subject($data['titulo']);
        $message->to($data['destinatario']);
        $message->attach($filename, array('mime' => "text/calendar"));
    });
```